# Empty variable PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

I have made this JS script which creates forms properly.

```
<script>

var proizvodac = ["Acer", "Apple", "Asus", "Dell", "HP", "Lenovo", "Toshiba"]

document.write('<form method="post" action="proizvodi.php">')
document.write('<input hidden="hidden" type="text" name="sqca" value="Laptop" />')
document.write('<button class="button" type="submit" name="submit">Laptop</button>')
document.write('</form>')

for (i = 0; i < proizvodac.length; i++){
    document.write('<div class="nav-bot">')
    document.write('<form method="post" action="proizvodi.php">')
    document.write('<input hidden="hidden" type="text" name="sqcp" value="Laptop" />')
    document.write('<input hidden="hidden" type="text" name="sqp" value="' + proizvodac[i] + '" />')
    document.write('<button type="submit" name="submit">' + proizvodac[i] + '</button>')
    document.write('</div>')
}
</script>
```

And here I have PHP code that work with those forms:

```
elseif(!empty($_POST['sqcp']) && !empty($_POST['sqp'])){

    $sqcp = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['sqcp']);
    $sqp = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['sqp']);
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Slika, Naziv, Opis, Cijena FROM Proizvodi WHERE Kategorija='$sqcp' AND Proizvodac='$sqp' ORDER BY Proizvodac");
}
```

Now my problem is that these two variables `$sqcp` and `$sqp` always return an empty string, even tho it should not.
Can someone tell me why?

Here's a debug part:

```
if (!empty($sqcp) && !empty($sqp)) echo $sqcp . ", " . $sqp;
else echo "Empty Variables";
}
```

Comment: Please always use {} around if statements, not doing so is a recipe for bugs.

Comment: First of all, you're not closing the form tag in your loop . No </form>

Comment: @Toby Allen: Oh, didn't know that, thanks for note.
Wow, how'd I miss that. I'll fix it immediately.

Comment: Try putting `print_r($_POST);` somwhere on top of your `proizvodi.php` file to see what exactly you are receiving as POST data.

Comment: @Majky: The problem was I didn't close the forms I was creating in for loops. It's good now. .)

Comment: The result of that javscript is N seperate forms. Which SUBMIT Button are you pressing as if you press the `Laptop` button you will not see the inputs from the other forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form tags are malformed. Remove this second `<form>` tag in the `for`:

```
document.write('<form method="post" action="proizvodi.php">')
```

Then move this line:

```
document.write('</form>')
```

to be after the `for`, outside of it.

Comment: Thank you, the missing closing tag of form was the problem. It works now.

Comment: Ok. keep all input fields you want to be posted inside the form.

Comment: You need to ask WHICH FORM. There are 8 on that page

Comment: That's not a good practice. In fact, as you can see in my answer I recommend to revert to have only one single form by removing/moving the tags appropriately. At that point, there's only one form and there's no way to get confused about which form I'm talking :)